# C++ Transporting runtime-conditional type information

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have a database which has 4 types of indexes. Each index type has a sort order. That is, if you know the static index type, then there is one correct functor to use to sort the objects in that index, and it is also known as soon as you know the index type, i.e. statically at compile time.

The database has a function which contains a runtime switch statement to decide which index to talk to. I would like that function to return runtime information from the index (iterators, mostly), but also, the static order type to use.

To show the intention, here is some pseudo-code. It does not work as is... could template specialization be used to write getLookupInfo (the return type would polymorphic). Note: I don't want to use virtuals.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Order>
struct LookupInfo {
  typedef Order order;
  uint64_t cost;
  Iterator it1, it2, it3, it4;
};

LookupInfo Database::getLookupInfo(LookupData data)
{
  if (data == ....) {
   return LookupInfo<Iterator1, Order1>();
  } 
   return LookupInfo<Iterator2, Order2>();
}

some_function(LookupInfo lookup_info) {
  vector<Record> records(lookup_info.begin(), lookup_info.end());
  sort(records.begin(), records.end(), lookup_info::order());
}
```

Is something like this at all possible?

Comment: I'm curious about how you expect `getLookupInfo` to work. I don't see how it might be called. The return statements don't match the return type, meaning you'll either need polymorphism or template specialization.

Comment: Andy - yes - that's where I'm not managing to close the loop. The code snippet will not work, it's more intended to show what I would like to do. And you are right, the trick is somehow to make the return type of getLookupInfo return me a different type each time. I don't want virtuals though, so I would like to use template specialization. But even that IMHO is tricky. The essence of my question is probably: how do I use template specialization to write getLookupInfo?

Comment: The trick is to turn everything into a type... I may be able to help if you give me some pseudo code for how you'd like to call it (w/o template specialization).

Comment: OK - what goes into getLookupInfo might as well be an int, whose value decides which type Order to use. What comes out of getLookupInfo should be something like the LookupInfo above, which carries some stuff, plus the type Order. If virtuals were possible, I guess there would be a virtual on LookupInfo to retrieve an instance of Order. Does that make sense?

Comment: what if you store all the possible `LookupInfo` types in a tuple, and `getLookupInfo` will store the result in that tuple, and return an index to it?
You will also need to template `some_function`. 
Also check `boost fusion`, it may be interesting for your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by collapsing your getLookupInfo -> apply some_function sequence into a single dispatch sequence. First, lets correct your definition of some_function to reflect the fact that it is a template function:

```
template<typename LookupInfo>
void some_function(LookupInfo lookup)
{
    vector<Record> records(lookup_info.begin(), lookup_info.end());
    sort(records.begin(), records.end(), lookup_info::order());
}
```

Next, introduce a helper functor to invoke it (for reasons I discuss below I can't skip this, much as I would like to):

```
template<typename LookupInfo>
struct some_functor
{
    void operator()(LookupInfo lookup_info)
    {   
        some_function<LookupInfo>(lookup_info);
    }   
};
```

Now for the dispatch trick. Forget your getLookupInfo function above, and instead define:

```
template<template <class L> class F>
void dispatchLookupInfo(int data)
{
  if (data == 0) {
    auto lookup = LookupInfo<Iterator1, Order1>();
    F<LookupInfo<Iterator1, Order1>> fn; 
    fn(lookup);
  }
  else  {
    auto lookup = LookupInfo<Iterator2, Order2>();
    F<LookupInfo<Iterator2, Order2>> fn; 
    fn(lookup);
  }   
}
```

Note here I'm pretending that `data` is an int as you said it might be. So as you can see instead of getting the LookupInfo and then calling the function separately, we do it in one go. Here dispatchLookupInfo takes a template template parameter, so it can specialise any function. This comes back to my point of needing a helper functor: I haven't been able to find a way to pass a function template (rather than a class template) as a template template parameter. However, clunky as it is I believe it satisfies your requirement of not involving virtual calls. Your final invocation might look like this:

```
dispatchLookupInfo<some_functor>(0);
```